# Object fit image not shrinking evenly

Tags: html, css

I used object fit contain to shove and image into a much smaller div. When the browser window width is reduced the images maintain aspect ratio but the part of the image shown starts to get cut off instead of uniformly resizing / shrinking.

Is there a way to use object fit without having part of images get cut off when window width is reduced?

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

.container{
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-direction: row;
}

.holder{
 height: 400px;
 width: 33.33%;
 padding-left: 5px;
 margin-top: 5px;
}

.last{

 padding-right: 5px;
}

img{
 object-fit: cover;
 object-position: 35% 25%;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
 <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="script/javascript.js"></script>
 <title> </title>
</head>

<body>
 
<div class="container">

 <div class="holder">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/660">
 </div>

 <div class="holder">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/660">
 </div>

 <div class="holder last">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/660">
 </div>

 <div class="holder">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/660">
 </div>

 <div class="holder">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/660">
 </div>

 <div class="holder last">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/660">
 </div>

</div>


<img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/660">


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can try object-fit: fill; to occupy the whole image in a given width div

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
object-fit: contain;
```

instead of cover

Comment: i considered that but i wanted the images to stay at the divs aspect ratio, thought that there might be a workaround or something

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.container{
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.holder{
  /* height: 400px; */
  width: 33.33%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.last{
  padding-right: 5px;
}
img{
  /* object-fit: cover; */
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: 35% 25%;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <title> </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="holder">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/660">
      </div>
      <div class="holder">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/660">
      </div>
      <div class="holder last">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/660">
      </div>
      <div class="holder">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/660">
      </div>
      <div class="holder">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/660">
      </div>
      <div class="holder last">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/660">
      </div>
    </div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/660">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code Hope this will Help For You!

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
.container{
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-direction: row;
}
.holder{
 height: 400px;
 width: 33.33%;
 padding-left: 5px;
 margin-top: 5px;
}

.last{

 padding-right: 5px;
}
img{
     object-fit: cover;
    /* object-position: 35% 25%; */
    object-fit: fill;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<body> 
<div class="container">
 <div class="holder">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/660">
 </div>
 <div class="holder">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/660">
 </div>
 <div class="holder last">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/660">
 </div>
 <div class="holder">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/660">
 </div>
 <div class="holder">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/660">
 </div>
 <div class="holder last">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/660">
 </div>
</div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/660">
</body>
```